# Inside result of regex matching

Tags: c++, regex

I have a character stream, producing one char each step.

- Step 1: produced character `'1'`, final string `'1'`
- Step 2: produced character `'2'`, final string `'12'`
- and so on...

Each step I want to know if the produced final string (sum of every char produced) has possibility to be matched by regexp in the future.

Example regex: `^\d{5}`

So the string `'123'` is not matched by this exact regex, but if the character stream produces two more digits, on the fifth step it would match.
But the string `'a12'` is already not matched and not possible to be matched in the future.

My question is - is there a possibility to separate those two cases in regex matching engine?
This looks like a FSM(finite state machine) task to check if the FSM has successful match, error or is in progress of its matching graph. I know that regex inside is FSM, but I don't know if it is possible to separate not matching case in two different cases as described above.

Comment: At worst, you might have 2 regexes, one final, and one for in progress (`^\d{0,5}`, might be more complicated to build for your real case though :/)

Comment: That's true, but the complexity of building sufficient number of internal regexes is going to be huge. You'd have to write one for each new word being produced.

Comment: In cases such as this I've often used [`boost::regex::regex_match`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) in conjunction with the [`boost::regex_constants::match_partial`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_flag_type.html) flag.

Comment: @G.M. this actually looks like what I was looking for. Thank you a lot. I would prefer you post it as the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the comment, you could make use of `boost::regex` and its [`boost::regex_constants::match_partial`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/partial_matches.html) flag...

```
boost::regex re("^(\\d{5})$");
boost::smatch caps;
std::string text = ...;
if (boost::regex_match(text, caps, re, boost::match_default | boost::match_partial) {

    /*
     * Matched successfully.  Need to decide whether or not match is partial.
     */
    if (caps[0].matched) {

        /*
         * Match is complete.
         */
    } else {

        /*
         * Match is partial.
         */
    }
}
```